# Spring Declarative Transaction Management with Neo4j server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j

We are working on a project with Spring Boot 2,Kotlin and neo4j server as our datastore. I was just playing around with Spring @Transactional annotation. After a quite long research on the internet, I found out there is no support for Spring transactions with Neo4j server(Rest API), it supports only for embedded Neo4j.spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j is used to configure neo4j

My Code is as follows

```
class ServiceImpl{

   @Throws(Throwable::class)
   @Transactional(rollbackFor = [Exception::class])
   public void create() {
       // Code for saving entity
       throw Exception("Failed to save") // Throwing exception intentionally to check rollback
   }
}
```

Entity saved is not rolled back even after exception is thrown. Same code works fine if database chosen in POSTGRES. However it does not work with Neo4j server if are using rest api for neo4j. Internet says support is only for embedded neo4j. Is there any other way of handling transactions efficiently. I know theres Springs programmatic transaction management, but that would be a tedious approach.

Any suggestions on this will be of great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Even programmatic transactions don't work. When you do a HTTP call (that is what REST is) you are invoking an external system, you cannot control a transaction over HTTP and hence it isn't supported. Regardless of you are using declarative or manual tx-management.

Comment: @M.Deinum So what is the recommended approach

Comment: How can you rollback a HTTP call?

Comment: @M.Deinum... Yes we cannot rollback HTTP call. Does bolt protocol works the same?

Comment: What version of Neo4j and SDN do you use?. Do you have `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your config? Show more of your code.

Comment: @M.Deinum of course you make a transactions work on top of (multiple) HTTP calls, it does not matter if it is HTTP or JDBC, or other (Bolt in Neo4j's case) all are remote. See https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/actions/ how Neo4j implements this. SDN implemented TransactionalManager on top of that. OP has a mistake somewhere if the rollback doesn't work.

Comment: @FrantišekHartman..We are using spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j dependency and neo4j version is 3.2.20

Comment: @M.Deinum...I will take a look into that site. Thanks for the info

Comment: It only works because an API has been defined, normally HTTP calls aren't transactional. There was also an attempt into transaction web services (WS-Transaction) and it wasn't that good. The issue using a inherent stateless protocol for things like this. Others are more low-level. Nonetheless if the driver supports this then indeed you can use the proper tx manager (and use the correct driver version) and you should have transactions.